# Breaking down String into array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String that I need to break down into chunks and hold each chunk in an array for manipulation. I don't know the length of the chunk but I do know that after the 8th comma a new record starts. I'm able to break it down to the correct chunk and store that in a `StringBuffer` within a loop but not sure how I would then add it to an array?

Code below shown what I've done so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                            //I would like to store each of these lines in an array
        String teachMod =  ("1,TSM,501,SM1056,Simon Thorne,TCO200,24,30,"+
                            "2,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO104,24,60,"+
                            "3,TSM,500,SM0156,Simon Thorne,TCO113,12,60,"+
                            "4,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO104,24,30,"+
                            "5,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO113,12,60,"+
                            "6,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO109,12,90,"+
                            "7,TSM,503,SM0156,Simon Thorne,CIS414,12,30,"+
                            "8,TSM,501,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO222,12,40,"+
                            "9,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO114,12,60,"+
                            "10,TSM,501,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO200,60,40,"+
                            "11,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO106,24,60,"+
                            "12,TSM,501,SM0156,Simon Thorne,TCO207,12,30,"+
                            "13,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO112,24,30,");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        char[] c = teachMod.toCharArray();
        int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < teachMod.length(); i++){
            sb.append(c[i]);
            if(c[i]==','){
                j++;
                if(j==8){
                    //At this point the variable sb holds what I want in an array
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    j=0;
                    sb = new StringBuffer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}//End class
```

Answer (score 2):

you could store them in an array like this:

```
String[] teachMod = { "first line", "second line" /* other line*/ };
```

Comment: I don't have control over the storage!

Answer (score 2):

```
//initialise array list which can store any length of chunks
ArrayList<String> chunks = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        char[] c = teachMod.toCharArray();
        int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < teachMod.length(); i++){
            sb.append(c[i]);
            if(c[i]==','){
                j++;
                if(j==8){
                    //At this point the variable sb holds what I want in an array
                    //add chunk to chunk list
                    chunks.add(sb.toString());
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    j=0;
                    sb = new StringBuffer();


                }
            }
        }
    //convert chunk list to array
    String[] chunksAsArray = chunks.toArray(new String[chunks.size()]);
```

Comment: Your welcome! Don't forget to accept (tick) this answer, please :)

Comment: this answer is too expensive but work but my answer is in one line and work

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
  ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]> ();
  String[] split = teachMod.split(",");

  for (int i = 0; i < split.length;) {
        String[] row = new String[8];
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++,i++){
           row[j]= split[i];
        }
        values.add(row);
  }

  String[][] rows = values.toArray(new String[0][]);
```

printing the array

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rows.length;i++) {         
     String s="";
     for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
           s=s+rows[i][j] + " ";
     }
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

output

```
1 TSM 501 SM1056 Simon Thorne TCO200 24 30 
2 TSM 500 AC1157 Peter Jones TCO104 24 60 
3 TSM 500 SM0156 Simon Thorne TCO113 12 60 
4 TSM 500 AC1157 Peter Jones TCO104 24 30 
5 TSM 500 AC1156 Richard Adlam TCO113 12 60 
6 TSM 500 AC1157 Peter Jones TCO109 12 90 
7 TSM 503 SM0156 Simon Thorne CIS414 12 30 
8 TSM 501 AC1156 Richard Adlam TCO222 12 40 
9 TSM 500 AC1156 Richard Adlam TCO114 12 60 
10 TSM 501 AC1157 Peter Jones TCO200 60 40 
11 TSM 500 AC1156 Richard Adlam TCO106 24 60 
12 TSM 501 SM0156 Simon Thorne TCO207 12 30 
13 TSM 500 AC1157 Peter Jones TCO112 24 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an array

```
String[] arr = new String[100];
int count = -1;
```

and add like this

```
        if(j==8){
            //At this point the variable sb holds what I want in an array

            array[++count] = sb.toString();

            System.out.println(sb);
            j=0;
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        }
```

Though i would suggest using Arraylist instead of arrays, because then you dont need to pre-determine the size.

```
  ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<Str>();
```

to add

```
            al.add(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

After get the line of 8 comma, you can generate array of String using `String[] arr=sb.toString().split(",")`

```
 if (j == 8) {
    //At this point the variable sb holds what I want in an array

    System.out.println(sb);
    String[] arr=sb.toString().split(",");
    for (String string : arr) {
        System.out.println("Arr value :"+string);
     }

    j = 0;
     sb = new StringBuffer();
  }
```

Comment: if sb already holds what is wanted in an array, why'd OP want split() it?

Answer (score 0):

There's some excellent suggestions already, but I was looking your algorithm and it just looked a little...long for me ;)

So I came up with this instead, which uses the fact that you know that a new record starts at each 8th comma.  Taking that I was able to split the `teachMod` `String` into an array and simply step by each record.

I simply used `System#arraycopy` to make a new sub copy of the array and added those to an `ArrayList`.

Now, somewhere in this mess, it would actually be possible to calculate the number of expected records, but I'm to lazy to be bothered ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BreakingString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String teachMod = ("1,TSM,501,SM1056,Simon Thorne,TCO200,24,30,"
                + "2,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO104,24,60,"
                + "3,TSM,500,SM0156,Simon Thorne,TCO113,12,60,"
                + "4,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO104,24,30,"
                + "5,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO113,12,60,"
                + "6,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO109,12,90,"
                + "7,TSM,503,SM0156,Simon Thorne,CIS414,12,30,"
                + "8,TSM,501,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO222,12,40,"
                + "9,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO114,12,60,"
                + "10,TSM,501,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO200,60,40,"
                + "11,TSM,500,AC1156,Richard Adlam,TCO106,24,60,"
                + "12,TSM,501,SM0156,Simon Thorne,TCO207,12,30,"
                + "13,TSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,TCO112,24,30,");
        String parts[] = teachMod.split(",");
        List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>(25);
        for (int index = 0; index < parts.length; index += 8) {
            String[] record = new String[8];
            System.arraycopy(parts, index, record, 0, 8);
            rows.add(record);
        }

        String[] recordRows = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()]);
    }

}
```